# How to sort multidimensional array in php order by array value. Array may contain duplicated values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have array $leaderboard. Which contains following data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ABC
            [time_taken] => 01:46:56
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => DEF
            [time_taken] => 00:21:54
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => MNO
            [time_taken] => 00:34:14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => PQR
            [time_taken] => 00:09:17
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => XYZ
            [time_taken] => 00:34:14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => STR
            [time_taken] => 00:34:14
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => LOK
            [time_taken] => 17:53:58
        )
}
```

I tried to sort the array on basis of time. Its working fine if time values not duplicate using ksort. But for duplicated time it only shows on record from that

Comment: look into [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or the like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<?php

$sortArray = array(array('name' => 'ABC',
                        'time_taken' => '01:46:56'),
                    array('name' => 'DEF',
                        'time_taken' => '00:21:54'),
                    array('name' => 'MNO',
                        'time_taken' => '00:34:14'),
                    array('name' => 'PQR',
                        'time_taken' => '00:09:17'),
                    array('name' => 'XYZ',
                        'time_taken' => '00:34:14'),
                    array('name' => 'LOK',
                        'time_taken' => '17:53:58'));
print_r($sortArray);
foreach ($sortArray as $key => $row) {
    $sorting[$key] = $row['time_taken'];
}
array_multisort($sorting, SORT_ASC, $sortArray);
print_r($sortArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4>function aasort (&$array, $key) {
<br>
    $sorter=array();<br>
    $ret=array();<br>
    reset($array);<br>
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {<br>
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];<br>
  <br>  }
    asort($sorter);<br>
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) <br>{

        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;<br>
}

aasort($your_array,"order");</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own sorting function and use uksort.
More about that: [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

Answer (score 0):

give it a try please..

```
function cmp( $a, $b ) { 
  if(  strtotime($a['time_taken']) ==  strtotime($b['time_taken']) ){ return 0 ; } 
  return (strtotime($a['time_taken']) < strtotime($b['time_taken'])) ? -1 : 1;
} 

usort($leaderboard,'cmp');
```

reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/9001655/829533

Comment: The shorter way is to return `strtotime($a['time_taken']) - strtotime($b['time_taken'])`

Comment: @Nitin_aeon does it work for you?

Comment: It shows top 2 records wrong. Otherwise its working.